# Need help in combining two queries into one

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help in combining two different queries into a single query; below are the queries which I'm using along with the outputs of the individual query.

Query 1:

```
SELECT 
   count( *) TestCount,
   asset 
FROM hsbc_csmip_dbprotect 
group by asset
```

Output 1:

```
     TestCount                       Asset
         18                     DB2MOTIV:DBMOTIVA@mxemch010405ads.mx.hsbc
         18                     IBASL01:BASL01@gbl05823.systems.uk.hsbc
         17                     ICOGP01:ITSCOG01@htng-icogp01.de.hsbc
         18                     ICTIP01:CTIP01@arp617fuc3db.ar.hsbc
         18                     IPSSP01:PSSP01@arp498fuc1db.ar.hsbc
         16                     IMXGP01:ITSMXG01@htng-imxgp01.de.hsbc
         19                     IINFP01:INFP01@gbl10805.systems.uk.hsbc
          9                     IHF4P01:HF4P01@mxcl0030006-dbai.mx.hsbc
         19                     IHQAL01:HQAL02@gbl07664.systems.uk.hsbc
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT 
   count( *) TestPassedCount,
   asset 
FROM hsbc_csmip_dbprotect 
where result_status = 'Not A Finding' 
group by asset
```

Output 2:

```
   TestPassedCount                Asset
          7                     DB2MOTIV:DBMOTIVA@mxemch010405ads.mx.hsbc
         16                     IBASL01:BASL01@gbl05823.systems.uk.hsbc
         11                     ICOGP01:ITSCOG01@htng-icogp01.de.hsbc
         10                     ICTIP01:CTIP01@arp617fuc3db.ar.hsbc
         11                     IPSSP01:PSSP01@arp498fuc1db.ar.hsbc
          9                     IMXGP01:ITSMXG01@htng-imxgp01.de.hsbc
         17                     IINFP01:INFP01@gbl10805.systems.uk.hsbc
          9                     IHF4P01:HF4P01@mxcl0030006-dbai.mx.hsbc
         18                     IHQAL01:HQAL02@gbl07664.systems.uk.hsbc
```

I would like to see the output as below

```
      TestCount          TestPassedCount        Asset
         18                      7              DB2MOTIV:DBMOTIVA@mxemch010405ads.mx.hsbc
         18                      16             IBASL01:BASL01@gbl05823.systems.uk.hsbc
         17                      11             ICOGP01:ITSCOG01@htng-icogp01.de.hsbc
         18                      10             ICTIP01:CTIP01@arp617fuc3db.ar.hsbc
         18                      11             IPSSP01:PSSP01@arp498fuc1db.ar.hsbc
         16                       9             IMXGP01:ITSMXG01@htng-imxgp01.de.hsbc
         19                      17             IINFP01:INFP01@gbl10805.systems.uk.hsbc
          9                       9             IHF4P01:HF4P01@mxcl0030006-dbai.mx.hsbc
         19                      18             IHQAL01:HQAL02@gbl07664.systems.uk.hsbc
```

Comment: Rather a JOIN...

Comment: @YogeshSharma UNION is not what they want. OP - look at how to use a join.

Comment: are these really two different tables or did you accidentally forget to mask the table name in the second query?

Comment: I've tried union and union all and is not working.

Comment: sorry they both are from the same table @SeanLange

Comment: Could you please provide the table definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since they are the same table, you can use a case statement.

```
SELECT 
    count( *) TestCount
    ,count(case when result_status = 'Not A Finding' then 1 end) TestPassedCount
    ,count(case when result_status = 'Not A Finding' then 1 end) / count(*) ThePercentage
    ,asset 
FROM hsbc_csmip_dbprotect
group by asset
```

Comment: Case _expression_. (It returns a value.)

Comment: thanks so much,this one is perfect and is giving me the output which I'm expecting.!!!

Comment: No problem @Vikas

Comment: Now I would like to generate the percentage value for both the columns i.e. for TestCount and TestPassedCount for example in the output for one of the asset 'DB2MOTIV:DBMOTIVA@mxemch010405ads.mx.hsbc' the Test Count is '18' and the TestPassedCount is '7' now the percentage for 7 & 18 is 38.89%, I want the percentage 38.89% in another column.

Comment: Usually you'd need to open a new question. But all you need is to divide the columns (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` statement like below :

```
SELECT count(*) AS TestCount
    ,count(case when result_status = 'Not A Finding' then 1 else 0 end) AS TestPassedCount, 
    asset 
FROM hsbc_csmip_dbprotect
group by asset
```